# Weird Memcached problem

Tags: php, memcached

I'm using Memcached with PHP, the code is like this :

```
$m = new Memcache;
$m->connect('myserver', 11213);

$key = ... // calculate key    

$value = $m->get($key); 
if($value) return $value

// calculate $value
$m->set($key, $value, 3600);
#var_dump($m->get($key);
```

Now weird thing is like this :

if I uncomment the var_dump line, I can see the data retrieved and dumped. That's right after it's pushed into Memcached. However, this line

```
$value = $m->get($key);
```

just always return false.

I'm sure the $key is consistent.

What possibly can go wrong?

Comment: Just tried my memcached server from telnet, get $key returns nothing :) weird.

Comment: Is this the complete code? You don't seem to ever be setting the key to something useful (i.e. you set it to $value, but $value is empty).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be confused about the third parameter. According to the documentation, it's for a flag, to enable compression (use `MEMCACHE_COMPRESSED`), and then the fourth is for a timeout (number of seconds, or a particular time in the future)

[`Memcache::set`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/memcache.set.php) `(string $key, mixed $var [, int $flag [, int $expire ]])`